# How do i call a parentfunction from a child class the inherits from a parent?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am currently working on a function, from which I want to call a parent function, from the child which is being passed to the function.

but cant seem to access the function in the parent.  Everything is public in the parent class.

So why can't from my child class access my parent function.

Example:

```
public class Parent 
{
    public parent();
    public void oblige();

}

public class child : parent
{
    public child();
    public void work();
}


public class house
{
    public house();
    public void child_labour(Child child)
    {
        //child.base.parent.oblige()?       
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error when you do `child.oblige()`?

Comment: I am not able to call the function, intellisense don't autocomplete..

Comment: Are you sure, the parent method is public? Are you sure you inherit correctly? It's probably a typo, but the parent class is `Parent` but the child class inherits from `parent`...

Comment: The code above is incorrect - casing issues all over the place.  If `Child` inherits from `Parent` and `Parent` has a public method `Oblige()`, then an instance of `Child` **_will_** have a public method `Oblige()`

Comment: See this example... **https://dotnetfiddle.net/i3GrCX**

Comment: @Archer *facepalm* I didn't notice `: parent` part. That's the only reason it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var house = new House();
        var child = new Child();
        house.child_labour(child);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Parent
{

    public void Oblige()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("CallOblige"); 
    }

}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public void Work()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child Working");   
    }
}


public class House
{

    public void child_labour(Child child)
    {
        child.Oblige();       
    }
}
```

When you run you'll get "CallOblige"

p.s. you need check C# syntax, as I can see you learning, too many silly errors.
You don't need a default constructor, for example.
All the best!

Answer (score -1):

First if all you must write consturctors, methods at least empty braces. Like this.

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {

    }

    public void Oblige()
    {

    }
}
```

The second you should read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels) to undertand basic principles of accessing.

Code example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        House house = new House();
        Child child = new Child();
        house.child_labour(child);
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {

    }

    public void Oblige()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child()
    {

    }

    public void Work()
    {

    }
}


public class House
{
    public House()
    {

    }

    public void child_labour(Child child)
    {
        child.Oblige();
    }
}
```